# pop up succcess message in the center of the screen, where all other elements positions are static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to create a pop up success message in the center of the screen AND with z-index greater than all the other elements, so that it appears in front of them. However all html elements in my page have style `display:static;` (content div, header, sidebar,etc..) so is it still possible to do so ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just set the popup to position fixed, left and top to 50% and the margin left and top to half of the size of the popup, and you're golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all elements are statically positioned, than yes, the pop-up message will always show up on top.  Static elements have a 0 z-index by default, so setting anything with a higher z-index and position:[relative, absolute, fixed] will place it on top.

Read more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) and css-tricks has a great overview/tutorial of z-index. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/